# JavaScript global error listener is not working

Tags: javascript

I am adding a global JavaScript error listening following this link, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror. I tried to test if the code is working by producing an error. But it is not working.

This is my code

```
var num = {

}

num.id.toString();

window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
    alert('Error');
    return false;
}
```

As you can see in my code above, it should alert message, 'Error' because id property of test object is undefined and so that calling `toString()` method on it will throw an error. But when I checked the console, I got the error. But the global error listener is not catching the error and triggered. How can I correctly set up the JavaScript global error listener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong order - you are trying to bind the event handler *after* an error that stops script execution. Turn that around:

```
window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
    alert('Error');
    return false;
}

var num = {

}

num.id.toString();
```

Comment: @WaiYanHein: don't forget to accept answers that help you. It is not strictly mandatory, but it is encouraged.

Comment: I just did. Cheers.